# SharePoint uses kerberos authentication communicate to AD and impact for changing password krbtgt Account

Tags: 2013, active-directory, security

Hi Is SharePoint uses kerberos authentication communicate to AD,SQL Server or any other Microsoft products by default ?

for product to product communication Microsoft using kerberos authentication by default?

for example domain/spfarm account microsoft uses Kerberos to communicate to AD,SQL SERVER?
what happened if Domain admin changes the password for krbtgt account? and any impact to running sharepoint farm after password changed ?farm ?

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn745899(v=ws.11).aspx#Sec_KRBTGT